# How to get the free space of my Google Drive without using the API?

Tags: powershell, google-drive-api, gmail, webrequest

I want to get the free space/quota in my google drive. I can achieve this using Google drive API. But i don't want to do this via API.

Can anyone help me to get this done via web request via PowerShell without API. I am looking for the below value as per image:

[image: Scrrenshot from Gmail account that shows the acquired space at downside]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.
We are not a coding service.
Please show us what you tried so far. Take a look at [tour], [ask] and try to offer a [mcve] of what you tried and where you failed.

Comment: I have posted my code, the problem is i dont want to go with API.

Comment: Dont post your code as an answer, edit your question, post it there and delete the answer.

Also we would like to an attempt how you tried it without the api, do some basic web invokes with powershell and try to get the mailbox informations with it.

Comment: The question says you want to access your drive quota, but then your answer says you want to access the Drive quotas of hundreds of accounts. Which is it?

Comment: the answer to your question is "you can't". Try asking a different question. Are these 100's of users in a Google domain?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access google drive programmaticly your going to have to use the Google Drive API thats the only way.  The Google drive api has a method called [About.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about/get)

> Gets information about the user, the user's Drive, and system capabilities.

request

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/about

response

```
{
 "storageQuota": {
  "limit": "125627793408",
  "usage": "14149023751",
  "usageInDrive": "2661743479",
  "usageInDriveTrash": "838401923"
 }
}
```

**Powershell**

I have not used the google drive api with powershell but i have used the [google analytics api](https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/eb95ed53c7ae18273434ff6b4789dc7d) with it.  Hardest part is the authentication the full code for that is here [Google Oauth Powershell](https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/55115de5e8b366be3969b24884f30a39#file-google-oauth-powershell)

```
Set-PSDebug -Off
Clear-Host
##########################################################################################################################
#
# Using refresh token to get new access token
# The access token is used to access an api by sending the access_token parm with any request. 
#  Access tokens are only valid for about an hour after that you will need to request a new one using your refresh_token
#
##########################################################################################################################

$clientId = "-9c6a8mimeradap3nn24ac76urlpdvhoe.apps.googleusercontent.com";
$secret = "jUFTGhA8Z7FelntdvUz10fP5";
$redirectURI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
$refreshToken = "1/t8yW_v0gnqudE3y0_J6RKOqV5ek25Whogp49leCGqt8";

$refreshTokenParams = @{
      client_id=$clientId;
      client_secret=$secret;
          refresh_token=$refreshToken;
      grant_type='refresh_token';
    }

$token = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" -Method POST -Body $refreshTokenParams 
"Response:" 

"Access Token:  $($token.access_token)"
```

after that it should just be a matter of

```
$data = Invoke-RestMethod -ContentType 'application/json' -Uri "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/about?access_token=$($token.access_token)" -Method GET
```

I didnt have time to test this its kind of an educated guess from my analytics example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer , but this i have already accomplished using Google Drive API. But my problem is this, i need to get this data from 100+ accounts, i cant configure each account to enable API and create credentials of each account. This is the reason i m asking if this can be achieve without API by calling web-request using simple gmail URL or any other method.

```
#GDrive variable
$ClientID = "<clientID>"
$ClientSecret = "<Secret>"
$RefreshToken = "<refreshtoken>"

function Get-GdriveAccessToken {

$params = @{
    Uri = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
    Body = @(
        "refresh_token=$RefreshToken", # Replace $RefreshToken with your refresh token
        "client_id=$ClientID",         # Replace $ClientID with your client ID
        "client_secret=$ClientSecret", # Replace $ClientSecret with your client secret
        "grant_type=refresh_token"
    ) -join '&'
    Method = 'Post'
    ContentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
$accessToken = (Invoke-RestMethod @params).access_token
}

function get-percentage {
# Set the authentication headers
$headers = @{
    'Authorization' = "Bearer $accessToken"
    'Content-type' = 'application/json'
}
$storage = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/about" -Headers $headers
$total = $storage.quotaBytesTotal
$used = $storage.quotaBytesUsed
$percentage = [math]::round($used/$total * 100)
}

try { Get-GDriveAccessToken }
CATCH { write-host " Error Occured duirng Access token grant, see below for the error details "
        $Gerror_1 = $_.exception
        write-host $Gerror_1.status -ForegroundColor Red
        write-host $Gerror_1.Response -ForegroundColor Red
        write-host $Gerror_1.Message -ForegroundColor Red
        write-host 
        break }

try { get-percentage }
CATCH { write-host " Error Occured duirng GDrive Access, see below for the error details "
        $Gerror_2 = $_.exception
        write-host $Gerror_2.status -ForegroundColor Red
        write-host $Gerror_2.Response -ForegroundColor Red
        write-host $Gerror_2.Message -ForegroundColor Red
        write-host 
        break }
```